# Actual GPU memory usage vs glDeleteXXXX?

Tags: opengl, memory, graphics, game-engine

Is the GPU driver is obliged to release GPU memory on demand from an application program? If not, does that kindof nullify any GPU memory resource management that an application might want to do, since it is a "layer removed" from the actual memory?

I'm allocating lots of textures and then freeing them. When allocating I can see the "GPU System Bytes" (in Process Explorer) rapidly increase (to an amount that hugely surpasses the images hard disk space - maybe they are uncompressed in GPU so take lots of space).

When freeing the textures, I can see the Texture2D object destructor correctly calls glDeleteTexture, but there seems to be a delay in the "GPU System Bytes" reducing back to the original value and in fact, the value does not return to the original value, it hovers above it a bit.

And then if keep doing this, I see the GPU memory usage gradually increases, but all the while, I am counting my glDeleteTexture calls, and the memory never quite seems to get recovered.

I am bamboozled, because from the app side it looks clean - x allocated, x freed - but I am seeing my application become a bit of resource hog, not in my process's memory space, but the GPU memory space, because of this (Intel HD 6000 GPU).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the GPU driver is obliged to release GPU memory on demand from an application program?

No. The OpenGL driver will return that memory whenever it feels like doing so.

> If not, does that kindof nullify any GPU memory resource management that an application might want to do, since it is a "layer removed" from the actual memory?

That's a consequence of using an API based on a hardware abstraction. If you wanted to avoid being "a layer removed from the actual memory", you should be using Vulkan.

Comment: Thanks for that. So is this how 3d graphical software products normally come up with the minimum requirements? Trial and error using different manufacturers graphics cards, monitoring actual usage vs the application experience to find the minimum acceptable spot? Ps Do AAA games then have to write specific code for each driver so that "it plays nice"?

Comment: @Laythe: The minimum requirements are mostly based on what is know about the amount of GPU resources a program will actively use throughout rendering a typical frame. When using OpenGL you're in practice not limited by what the GPU has to offer. It's perfectly possible (if the driver support is) to allocated way more graphics resources (textures, vertex buffers and such) as fit into GPU memory. Also modern GPUs can move stuff from/to system memory on demand.

Comment: @Laythe: However it is true that many applications do contain special code paths for particular OpenGL implementations (drivers/GPUs) to tweak certain aspects. In the same way also the drivers of NVidia and AMD will actually hot-inject patch code into certain applications to fix problems and to improve performance.

Comment: Wow. I am only just getting into graphics, but I must say that we are left to the behest so much is quite crappy. What does an app that does not know in advance its workload do? All I want is a delete that does a .. delete. In my case the Intel graphics driver is refusing to release memory, and my app can and does demand more new memory (because we previously freed memory), but since the Intel driver has not released *my freed* memory, the laptop I'm running on ends up "all fans blazing" after not too long...

Comment: @Laythe: "all fans blazing" is an issue that should not be caused by lack of memory resources, unless all the shuffling around of data causes high CPU load, which it normally doesn't. For what it's worth with a properly written OpenGL driver you can just allocate new textures/buffers and let the old stuff pile up. It will consume some system RAM and may cause excessive swapping. *You do not have to delete a texture to make "room" for new data.* There's a reason why `glDeleteTextures`/`glDeleteBuffers` take a point to an array and not just single values.

Comment: @datenwolf If I want my application to page in and out of 100,000 high resolution images seamlessly and as required in response to user input, then the application needs to manage its own demands to the driver, otherwise the system grinds to a halt (runs of of process virtual mem). Ps. I know the Intel drivers have a  bad rep generally - Is the Intel driver within your definition of a "properly written driver"?

Comment: @Laythe: There is not *the* Intel GPU driver. There are several drivers for the Intel GPU with very different quality. The drivers for Windows are on the lower end of the quality spectrum in both performance and buginess. The open source drivers which are part of Mesa/DRI have a very high code quality, with better support for modern OpenGL, but the performance is still a weak point.

Comment: @Laythe: Regarding swapping out textures, if you really want to optimize on that front you should use streaming techniques like buffer orphaning by replacing the buffer object, keeping the ID. Regarding textures it makes sense to keep around a pool of texture objects of various sizes and formats and just *updating* their data with `glTexSubImage` instead of going through a full recreation.

Comment: @Laythe: However if you really want that low level control over allocations then you really should look into Vulkan.